# Sql Server - Sumar resultado de una query con condicional y subconsulta

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo la siguiente query, la cual posee una subquery, de la cual extraigo informacion de 3 tablas

```
SELECT
    ta.*,
    CASE WHEN ta.Avg6 = 0 THEN 100
        ELSE round(CAST(CAST((ta.Disp / ta.Avg6) AS DECIMAL(10,2)) AS FLOAT), 2, 1)
    END AS Meses,
    SUM(
        CASE WHEN tb.ESTADO <> 'INGRESADO - DISPONIBLE' AND tb.ESTADO <> 'POR CONFIRMAR EMBARQUE' 
            AND tb.DISPONIBILIDAD <= CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEADD(d,1,GETDATE()), 105)
            THEN tb.[Shp Qty] ELSE 0 END
    ) AS Sem0
FROM (
    SELECT
        t1.Codigo_producto AS Codigo,
        t2.Nombre_Producto AS Descripcion,
        SUM(t1.Cantidad_Disponible) AS Disp,
        SUM(t1.Cantidad_transito) AS Tto,
        SUM(t1.Ventas_backorder) AS BO,
        CAST(CAST((
            (SUM(t1.Venta_01 + t1.Venta_02 + t1.Venta_03 + t1.Venta_04 + t1.Venta_05 + t1.Venta_06) / 6) +
            (SUM(t1.NoVenta_01 + t1.NoVenta_02 + t1.NoVenta_03 + t1.NoVenta_04 + t1.NoVenta_05 + t1.NoVenta_06) / 6)
        ) AS DECIMAL(10,1)) AS FLOAT) AS Avg6
    FROM FactLogisticaInventario AS t1
    LEFT JOIN DimProducto AS t2
        ON t1.Codigo_producto = t2.Codigo_Producto
    WHERE t2.Clasificacion_Producto = 'Insumo'
        AND t1.Bodega = '1E'
        AND t1.Estado_stock IN ('Bueno', 'Usado')
    GROUP BY t1.Codigo_producto, t2.Nombre_Producto, t2.gl_consolidacion
) AS ta
LEFT JOIN disponibilidad_transito AS tb
    ON ta.Codigo = tb.CODIGO
GROUP BY ta.Codigo, ta.Descripcion, ta.Disp, ta.Tto, ta.BO, ta.Avg6
```

El detalle viene aca, y es que necesito una forma de poder obtener otro resultado, basado en el resultado del case **Sem0**, que es basicamente otra suma con condicional, el cual explico aqui abajo:

```
SUM(
        CASE WHEN tb.ESTADO <> 'INGRESADO - DISPONIBLE' AND tb.ESTADO <> 'POR CONFIRMAR EMBARQUE' 
            AND tb.DISPONIBILIDAD <= CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEADD(d,8,GETDATE()), 105)
            THEN tb.[Shp Qty] - Sem0 ELSE 0 END
    ) AS Sem1
```

En donde, en esta suma, si se cumple la condicional, se debe sumar el total del campo **[Shp Qty]** - el total obtenido en **Sem0**, y esto debo repetirlo en cadena (Calcular Sem2 con el resultado de Sem1... etc)

---

Como me pidieron, para que se entienda aprox.
De la primera tabla, extraigo la informacion de los productos y su stock

| Codigo | Disp | Tto | BO |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0520C00 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1284C00 | 0 | 3 | 0 |
| 1284C00 | 3 | 0 | 0 |
| 2088V00 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

De la segunda, solo la descripcion del producto y parte de los filtros

| Descripcion |
| --- |
| SX500 STARTER KIT |
| AW35 TONER |
| D1A310 TONER |
| 9PXS TONER |

Entonces, de esta primera query, extraigo la informacion de Disponibles, Transito y Backorder, mas la descripcion, ademas de calcular el promedio de ventas y no ventas (Avg6), el cual me devuelve algo asi:

| Codigo | Descripcion | Disp | Tto | BO | Avg6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0520C00 | SX500 STARTER KIT | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1284C00 | AW35 TONER | 0 | 3 | 0 | 1 |
| 1284C00 | D1A310 TONER | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2088V00 | 9PXS TONER | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

Entonces, con esta informacion, utilizo otra query por encima, para extraer estos datos y ademas calcular la columna **Meses**, la cual es una division entre `Disp / Avg6` y **Sem0**, el cual es la suma total de cada producto proveniente del campo **[Shp Qty]** que pertenece a la tabla disponibilidad_transito, el cual el producto este en un estado distinto a 'INGRESADO - DISPONIBLE' y 'POR CONFIRMAR EMBARQUE', ademas que su fecha de embarque sea menor a la fecha posterior al dia actual. Todo esto dandome un resultado asi:

| Codigo | Descripcion | Disp | Tto | BO | Avg6 | Meses | Sem0 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0520C00 | SX500 STARTER KIT | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 100 | 120 |
| 1284C00 | AW35 TONER | 0 | 3 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 5 |
| 1284C00 | D1A310 TONER | 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 100 | 11 |
| 2088V00 | 9PXS TONER | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 100 | 33 |

Hasta ahi todo bien, pero ahora debo hacer los demas calculos, que serian `Sem 1 al 6`, el cual el calculo es la misma que Sem0, pero con la diferencia que el resultado se debe restar a lo obtenido en Sem0.

Espero se entienda y me puedan ayudar con esto, que me tiene entrampado.

Comment: un ejemplo nunca viene mal...

Comment: Ahi agregue un ejemplo mas abajo

Comment: eso.. es otro query gigante.. igual que el primero.. un ejemplo.. son datos de entrada y datos de salida ;)

Comment: Ahi publique datos con mas detalles

Comment: Se entiende bien lo que voy necesitando?

Comment: si.. si dependes de la columna que acabas de calcular, mejor hacer querys sucesivos.. si lo pones todo en el mismo query, salvo que uses clausulas with enormes, te va a quedar un select monstruosamente grande...

Comment: Es que eso es lo que quiero evitar y poder buscar una forma mas sencilla de poder calcular todo.

Comment: Y eso como seria? no hay otra forma... querys sucesivos... si no, vas a calcular el mismo valor montones de veces...

Comment: Opte por usar WITH, me resulto lo que necesitaba, pero ni se imaginan la bestialidad de query que quedo.